# Python Sockets IP address mistake

Tags: python, windows, sockets

I try to recreate a program demonstrated in a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKwVn0k1krQ).

Some information about my software: Windows 11, Python 3.10.4 from https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3104/ ("Windows embeddable package (64-bit)" at the end of the site)

I have typed in the basic code from 19:40 of the video and now try to run the server.py script:

```py
import socket

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 100))
server_socket.listen(1)
while True:
    (client_socket, addr) = server_socket.accept()
    print(client_socket.recv(1024))
```

I replaced the `0.0.0.0` with my actual IP address from https://whatismyipaddress.com/. If I try to run the script, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "My Path\server.py", line 5, in <module>
    server_socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", 100))
OSError: [WinError 10049] Die angeforderte Adresse ist in diesem Kontext ungültig
```

The german part can be translated to `The requested address is invalid in this context`

Can anybody explain what this means and how I can fix it?

Comment: You can keep the ip as is - ‘0.0.0.0’, it means listen for incoming packets on all interfaces to my ip. BTW I suspect the ip on the website you checked was incorrect (it might have found the ip of your router), please check in your cmd the output of ‘ipconfig’

Comment: Read up a bit on network address translation, or [NAT](https://superuser.com/search?q=nat), on superuser.

Comment: Your computer doesn't know it has that IP address. Your computer thinks it has a different IP address. The router is tricking it. This is a horrible and dumb thing that we all decided to do so that we could pretend we didn't run out of IP addresses, and if your connection has IPv6 you should use IPv6 instead.